# Best way to store encryption keys without HSM or some other secret storage device

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, secret-key

How can I securely manage my encryption keys such that when someone intruded the system, they will at the very least have a hard time trying. I know this sounds a bit absurd, but since we cannot afford to have HSMs or Hashicorp's vault which I really think is cool. As of now, our keys are stored on a file located on a folder.

Comment: Take a look to this question [where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption).

Comment: Thanks for the really helpful link. Didn't know that there is another site for security and stuff.